# ionic cordova build android Error Execution failed for Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavacC

Tags: typescript, firebase, cordova, ionic-framework, javac

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3hZB.jpg)

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavacC:\Users\anonymous\Documents\Myapp\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePlugin.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
>   import android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat;
>                                ^
>     symbol:   class NotificationManagerCompat
>     location: package android.support.v4.app
>   C:\Users\anonymous\Documents\Myapp\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePlugin.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
>   import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
>                                ^
>     symbol:   class NotificationCompat
>     location: package android.support.v4.app
>   C:\Users\anonymous\Documents\Myapp\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePlugin.java:40: error: package me.leolin.shortcutbadger does not exist
>   import me.leolin.shortcutbadger.ShortcutBadger;
>                                  ^
>   C:\Users\anonymous\Documents\Myapp\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePluginMessagingService.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
>   import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
>                                ^
>     symbol:   class NotificationCompat
>     location: package android.support.v4.app

C:\Users\anonymous\Documents\Myapp\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePlugin.java:119: error: cannot find symbol

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
>   33 actionable tasks: 10 executed, 23 up-to-date

```
    int visibility = channel.optInt(VISIBILITY, NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
                                                ^
```

symbol:   variable NotificationCompat
  location: class FirebasePlugin
C:\Users\anonymous\Documents\Myapp\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePlugin.java:452: error: cannot find symbol
                    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
                    ^
  symbol: class NotificationManagerCompat
C:\Users\anonymous\Documents\Myapp\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePlugin.java:452: error: cannot find symbol
                    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
                                                                          ^
  symbol: variable NotificationManagerCompat
C:\Users\anonymous\Documents\Myapp\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePlugin.java:473: error: cannot find symbol
                    ShortcutBadger.applyCount(context, number);
                    ^
  symbol: variable ShortcutBadger
C:\Users\anonymous\Documents\Myapp\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePluginMessagingService.java:144: error: package NotificationCompat does not exist
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId);
                              ^
C:\Users\anonymous\Documents\Myapp\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePluginMessagingService.java:144: error: package NotificationCompat does not exist
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId);
                                                                                   ^
C:\Users\anonymous\Documents\Myapp\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePluginMessagingService.java:153: error: cannot find symbol
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX);
                                 ^
  symbol:   variable NotificationCompat
  location: class FirebasePluginMessagingService
C:\Users\anonymous\Documents\Myapp\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePluginMessagingService.java:149: error: package NotificationCompat does not exist
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(messageBody))
                                                    ^
C:\Users\anonymous\Documents\Myapp\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePluginMessagingService.java:148: error: cannot find symbol
                    .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                                   ^
  symbol:   variable NotificationCompat
  location: class FirebasePluginMessagingService
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
13 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

  > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 0s
C:\Users\anonymous\Documents\Myapp\platforms\android\gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
C:\Users\anonymous\Documents\Myapp\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePlugin.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat;
                             ^
  symbol:   class NotificationManagerCompat
  location: package android.support.v4.app
C:\Users\anonymous\Documents\Myapp\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePlugin.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
                             ^
  symbol:   class NotificationCompat
  location: package android.support.v4.app
C:\Users\anonymous\Documents\Myapp\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePlugin.java:40: error: package me.leolin.shortcutbadger does not exist
import me.leolin.shortcutbadger.ShortcutBadger;
                               ^
C:\Users\anonymous\Documents\Myapp\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePluginMessagingService.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
                             ^
  symbol:   class NotificationCompat
  location: package android.support.v4.app
C:\Users\anonymous\Documents\Myapp\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePlugin.java:119: error: cannot find symbol
        int visibility = channel.optInt(VISIBILITY, NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
                                                    ^
  symbol:   variable NotificationCompat
  location: class FirebasePlugin
C:\Users\anonymous\Documents\Myapp\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePlugin.java:452: error: cannot find symbol
                    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
                    ^
  symbol: class NotificationManagerCompat
C:\Users\anonymous\Documents\Myapp\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePlugin.java:452: error: cannot find symbol
                    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
                                                                          ^
  symbol: variable NotificationManagerCompat
C:\Users\anonymous\Documents\Myapp\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePlugin.java:473: error: cannot find symbol
                    ShortcutBadger.applyCount(context, number);
                    ^
  symbol: variable ShortcutBadger
C:\Users\anonymous\Documents\Myapp\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePluginMessagingService.java:144: error: package NotificationCompat does not exist
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId);
                              ^
C:\Users\anonymous\Documents\Myapp\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePluginMessagingService.java:144: error: package NotificationCompat does not exist
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId);
                                                                                   ^
C:\Users\anonymous\Documents\Myapp\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePluginMessagingService.java:153: error: cannot find symbol
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX);
                                 ^
  symbol:   variable NotificationCompat
  location: class FirebasePluginMessagingService
C:\Users\anonymous\Documents\Myapp\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePluginMessagingService.java:149: error: package NotificationCompat does not exist
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(messageBody))
                                                    ^
C:\Users\anonymous\Documents\Myapp\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePluginMessagingService.java:148: error: cannot find symbol
                    .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                                   ^
  symbol:   variable NotificationCompat
  location: class FirebasePluginMessagingService
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
13 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

  > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 0s
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

```
    cordova.cmd build android exited with exit code 1.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```